ASP.NET is there a way to map a specific endpoint to a static html file?
i would like to map a custom endpoint to an html file like localhost:3000/page taking you to somePage.html. I tried using app.UseFileServer as described in the asp.net docs for static files like this
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\somePage.html")),
    RequestPath = "/page",
});

but i realized it is meant for mapping a directory not individual files and nothing else on that page seemed to do what i want, unless i missed it.
i also thought about using a redirect like this
app.MapGet("/page", () => Results.Redirect("/somePage.html"));

but i don't want the url to be localhost:3000/somePage.html, i want it to be localhost:3000/page. so i can't use that.
i figured i could just read the file to a variable and return it like this
string currDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
byte[] somePageHtml = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(currDir, @"wwwroot\somePage.html"));

app.MapGet("/page", () =>
{
    return Results.File(somePageHtml, "text/html");
});

which works, but i was wondering is there is a way i am supposed to do this in asp.net? also could my method cause problems in the future? i don't know how many or how big my html files will be, is it a bad idea to keep them in memory like this?

Are you sure you need to map anything? Files in wwwroot are already mapped by the call to app.MapStaticAssets(); which is added by. If you want to map some file outside that folder, you can just use the path, eg app.MapGet("/page", () =>Results.File(fullpath, "text/html"));. You don't need to load the contents in advance

i upgraded my project to .net 9 and used it like you said and it worked. thank you.

This works in previous versions too although the methods may be slightly different. All web apps require some static content. The FileResult type and the File methods that create it always accepted a Stream, byte[] or string path parameter too. It's impractical to load large files, eg videos,  in memory. HTTP allows requesting a specific byte range too. With a stream/file-backed FileResult, only the required bytes are loaded

Create a View and Controller for "SomePage"
Inject the Raw HTML into the view
@Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("/Somelocation/SomePage.html"));
